# how to run postgre sql query with param with many different values?

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

so if I have some simple insert queries like below,

```
INSERT INTO user_test_score
(test_id, date_occured, number_of_questions, user_id, score)
VALUES (123,'2023-03-30', 100, $1, $2)
```

can I run it in dbeaver with array of `(user_id,score)`?

what I did is generating all the queries first with some programming

thanks

bind parameter only accept single value, so it passes the array, not the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unnest` can be used to convert array to a table

```
select some_table_name.*
from unnest(Array[1,2,3], Array[95,88,100]) as some_table_name(user_id,score);
```

and then insert query can be written as

```
insert into user_test_score (test_id, date_occured, number_of_questions, user_id, score)
select
  123 as test_id,
  '2023-03-30' as date_occured,
  100 as number_of_questions,
  user_id_score_table.user_id,
  user_id_score_table.score
from
  unnest(Array[1,2,3], Array[95,88,100]) as user_id_score_table(user_id,score);
```